# New row is not adding when all rows have been deleted in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a form inside a table. In that table I have row for input fields. I have two options for remove row and add line. In add line when user will click a new row will be added and when user will click on remove row the last row will be removed. All this is working fine. But I have a problem that suppose I have clicked on remove row option and the last row will be removed and in this way all the rows are removed. Again now when I am clicking on add line it is not adding a new row. So can some one solve this? Here is the complete code for this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-IN">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.7.2.js"></script>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
  table td {
    border: 1px solid #666;
  }
</style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#add-line").click(function() {
      var row = jQuery('.form-fields tbody>tr:last').clone(true);
      row.find("input:text").val("");
      row.insertAfter('.form-fields tbody>tr:last');
      return false;
    });
    jQuery('#remove-row').live('click',function(event){
      jQuery(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
  });
</script>

  <div id="form">
  <table id="form-headings">
    <tr>
      <td width="15%">Remove Rows</td>
      <td width="15%">Product</td>
      <td width="16%">Description</td>
      <td width="13%">Unit Cost</td>
      <td width="14%">Quantity</td>
      <td width="12%">Discount</td>
      <td width="14%">Total</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="form-fields">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" id="remove-row" value="Remove Row" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="form_product" size="5px"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="form_description" size="5px"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="form_unit_cost" size="5px"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="form_quantity" size="5px"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="form_discount" size="5px"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="form_total" size="5px"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="add-line" value="Add Line" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you do not have a tr able to clone when you delete the last row in the table.

In the code you are cloning and then appending it to the table..

**UPDATED CODE**

Also this part of your code is wrong

```
var row jQuery('.form-fields tbody>tr:last').clone(true);
row.insertAfter('.form-fields tbody>tr:last');
```

As once the last row is removed you wont find the tr>last .. It will return false.. So try avoiding it..

You can create a dummy row that holds this row structure and clone it from there..

I have created a .prototype class that holds the row.. Cloning it and inserting it..

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/74p5v/)

Comment: then how to do this? What is the best solution to solve this?

Comment: @sushanta reddy ok..Fine its working here. Can you tell me what is the use of prototype here?

Comment: It is for storing the structure of the row to be added

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the `#add-line` button, it clones the last row in your table and inserts it at the end of the table. This does not work after you have removed all the rows because there is **no last row to clone** (it does not exist). Moreover, you are inserting the clone after the last row, which again does not exist so it does not insert it anywhere.

I would recommend using jQuery to **create a new row, assign attributes as needed, and then append it to your `tbody`**.

Something like this should work:

```
var row =
    jQuery('<tr/>')
    .append(jQuery('<td/>')
        .append('<input/>', {
            type: text,
            ...
        })
    .append(...)
    ...
    .appendTo('.form-fields tbody')
;
```

Another option is to **create a sample row you can create a clone of, and then append that your `tbody`**. You can have the sample row in your markup with `display: none`, or you can create it and have it available in your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no row left to clone. You can guard against that by either creating it on the fly, or keeping a row in a hidden div, and cloning that one.

Then you are telling JQuery to insert after the last TR, and there is no TR left. Change it to append to the table: `$('.form-fields tbody').append(row);`